# uniform convergence of $f_n(x) = \frac{nx}{1+n^2x^2}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

I have this sequence, $$ f_n(x) = \frac{nx}{1+n^2x^2} $$
I have to say if this sequence is uniform convergent,

based on the definition of uniform convergence, a sequence is uniform convergent if this limit exists: $$\lim_{n\to \infty}(\sup(|f_n(x) - f(x)|)) = 0$$

I've found that f(x) = 0, and therefore limit becomes easier: $$\lim_{n\to \infty}(\sup(|f_n(x)|)) = 0$$

now I have to find the absolute maximum of this sequence, and in theory I have to study the function by taking the derivative (using quotient rule in this case), but I think there is a faster approach:

- finding the domain of the function,
- if the upper bound is equal to infinity, then it doesn't converge.

in this case, domain is $${-\infty, +\infty}$$ so it doesn't make sense to find convergence. Is it legit to use this method? or should I always do the longer approach involving the first derivative?

Comment: Presumably you are defining $f_n$ on $\mathbb{R}$ (or $[0,\infty)$ by symmetry).

Comment: Observe that $f_n(\frac{1}{n})=1/2$ for all $n.$ Consequence ?

Comment: We have $f_n(x)=g(nx)$ where $g(x)={x\over 1+x^2}.$ The sequence of this type is not uniformly convergent unless the function $g$ is constant.

Comment: @Fred how do you know that you have to solve f_n using 1/n? I'm trying to understand that step

Comment: @GabrielBurzacchini A sequence of functions $(f_n)_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ in $A$, if and only if for all numerical sequences $(x_n)_{n}$ defined over $A$, $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left| f_n(x_n) - f(x_n) \right| = 0$. This means that if you found at least one sequence that does not satisfy this criteria, $(f_n)_n$ does not converge uniformly.